What should be the room description of "the Side Channel"?
If you didn't already know, we do have a chat room for general discussion called the Side Channel. As for the details of finding this awesome name, look into "Should we name our chat room?".
Now what kinda bothered me was the room description. Right now this reads:

General discussion for crypto.stackexchange.com

Which is really boring and uninspiring.
So I'd like to ask here for suggestions for the room descriptions which are more interesting / inspiring / less boring and generic.
In your answer, please start with your suggested description (properly formatted) and then also provide some reasoning.
The usual voting rules apply:

Upvote if you want to see the description.
Downvote if you actively don't want to see this description.


To avoid this being an open question forever, first action will be taken on February the 28th at 23:59UTC at which point the currently most upvoted answer will be made the room description. If at a later point any answer outscores the leading answer the description will be updated.

This post stands in a tradition of community-consensus votes on random things. Like the close reasons, the above linked room name and the community promotion ads.

http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35747215#35747215 (Don’t forget to accept CurveEnthusiast’s answer to wrap it up.)


Mostly randomly generated noise.

A play on the fact that side-channels can be rendered useless by adding random noise. The same is true for chat rooms: they can quickly degenerate to many intertwined completely off-topic "random" discussions.
Like in the case of side-channels, there is still relevant important information somewhere in between all that noise (i.e. key-related data vs. good discussions), which is in the end what we look for!

Or maybe the good stuff has been encrypted...

Congrats… your suggestion won! http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35747215#35747215


The one-stop-shop for all your entropy needs.


A play on the fact that chat rooms tend to be chaotic and random and thus potentially a "good" source of entropy.


Cryptographically Insecure Random Noise Generator



Putting the infinite monkey theorem to the test.


A play on the fact that chat rooms tend to be "random" and quite often not on-topic and thus "a bunch of monkeys who write random stuff for a long period of time and eventually produce something useful".

Are you volunteering for the MR department?

@CodesInChaos MR?

@SEJPM Monkey Ressources as opposed to HR ;)


Warning: Must listen real close to get anything useful.


Leaking useful information, one bit at a time.


Noise with some hidden information.



Padding the oracle towards quantum randomness...


Something like:

For unbounded queries

or 

For adversaries with unbounded queries



Talk beyond the ciphertext...



24 hour key party people


A play on the fact that chat rooms tend to be active at the weirdest times and that there's always "party" going on, with a special twist for the cryptographer's "fetish" for key parties.


The elliptic curve pageant.


A play on the fact that cryptographers are a lot into elliptic curves and that the chat room may or may not end up as a spectacular celebration of this.

Love it. Not hopeful it's going to make it :-)

While I like CurveEnthusiasts's play on side channels and noise, I keep feeling it's missing something.

Mostly indistinguishable from randomly generated noise.

(Or without “mostly”?)


General discussion for
  crypto.stackexchange.com


This is the default, generic room description.
